# Scrolling effect like iCal's week view in Lion

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am working on cocoa for 1 month. I am working on application where I need to have my own custom week view, which is more compact then ical, but what I want is the nice scrolling animation which ical gives when we move from one week to another.

Currently I am using NSView Animation, having two views, one is buffer view and one is main view. What i do is before animation i put buffer view in the right position then simply changes the both views, frame origin to get the animation effect. So far it does the job but doesn't seems to be as good as ical.

I tried core graphics but couldn't able to get the same scrolling effect which ical gives.